# Prevent css columns inheritance?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, html-lists

I have a container with `columns: 2` but I would like to apply to all the children except `<ul>`

Is there any way? tried to set `columns: 1` to the `<ul>` but won't achieve it..

```css
.text {
  columns: 2;
  
  /* irelevant */
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text ul {
  columns: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Here is going to split the text in two columns</p>
  <p>Which i what I want</p>
</div>

<div class="text">
  <ul>
    <li>I dont want to happen</li>
    <li>For list items</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're actually splitting `.text` into two columns. if that's the intention and you want to any `.text` that contains a `ul` to have only one column, that's not possible with CSS as there's no parent selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code in your css:

```
.text ul {
    width: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: the `width: 200%` doesn't seem to be required.

Comment: but we can't control parent class in css, you can add another parent class with .text class and change columns:1 @ToniMichelCaubet

Comment: huh? I don't understand the comment. I meant that with just the `display: inline-block` it seems to be enough